# How to conditionally specify an XML schema type with XSLT and Saxon

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery, saxon

Im using this [merge.xslt](http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/#merge) script to merge several different XML files into one. This tool is very useful and includes a `dontmerge` command-line parameter so that certain XML elements wont be merged. The problem is that only one XML element can be specified, and I need to be able to specify multiple XML elements that shouldnt be merged. I could just add more command-line parameters to the script, like `dontmerge2`, `dontmerge3`, etc but this isnt an elegant solution.

While studying the particular XML elements that should ***not*** be merged, I realized that they are all of the same XML schema type, as follows:

```
<xs:element name="doCliCommand" type="cliParametersT">
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="undoCliCommand" type="cliParametersT">
</xs:element>
```

So, instead of using `dontmerge` for both `doCliCommand` and `undoCliCommand`, I would like to be able to do something like `dontmergetype=cliParametersT`

The relevant part of the `merge.xslt` is the following:

```
  <xslt:param name="dontmerge" />
  ...
  <xslt:when test="$type1='element' and $type2='element' and
                   local-name($node1)=local-name($node2) and
                   namespace-uri($node1)=namespace-uri($node2) and
                   name($node1)!=$dontmerge and name($node2)!=$dontmerge">
```

So here is the question: How do I modify this particular xslt test condition to be able to test for the XML schema type? I havent found any appropriate XPath, XQuery, or XSLT functions to get the schema type.

There is a somewhat related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8323452/1158895) where they mention that this cant be done unless using Saxon extensions. Im using SaxonHE9-5-1-3J.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check in XPATH if a type is equal to a type or derived from the type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323452/how-to-check-in-xpath-if-a-type-is-equal-to-a-type-or-derived-from-the-type)

Comment: @ceving good point. I see that in the answer provided they say its not possibleto do what Im asking unless using Saxon or related extensions. I am using Saxon, so perhaps I should modify the question accordingly, because I dont know how to use these Saxon extensions.

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use or can you use? There are schema-aware XSLT 2.0 processors that might help. MSXML 6 is an XSLT 1.0 processor but also has its own proprietary schema support, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256453%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I updated the question to mention that Im using Saxon HE 9-5-1-3J.

Comment: @Brady, the Home Edition of Saxon is not schema-aware I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a schema-aware XSLT 2.0 processor such as Saxon-EE, you can write

```
<xsl:when test=". instance of element(*, cliParametersT)">
```

You need to make sure that the schema is imported into the stylesheet using `xsl:import-schema`, and you need to make sure that the source document is actually validated against the schema (with Saxon, use -val:strict on the command line).

Comment: Sounds like it needs to be hard-coded into the xslt, considering I also need to import the schema? I was hoping to make it configurable on the command line.

Comment: @Brady: You are using Saxon-HE which is not schema-aware. In other words, with your edition of the Saxon processor, XML cannot be validated against a schema.

Comment: Right, but what if I switch to the EE version? Would the schema still need to be imported?

Comment: Yes, adding `<xsl:import-schema>` as a top-level declaration to the stylesheet ("merge.xslt", I suppose) is most straightforward. Also have a look at: http://saxonica.com/documentation9.4-demo/html/schema-processing/satransformcmd.html

Comment: Testing membership of a type whose name is not known statically could be done using dynamic XPath evaluation (xsl:evaluate in 3.0, or saxon:evaluate), or using the extension function saxon:type-annotation.